# Efficient mean and total aggregation over multiple Pandas DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

|  | id | country | grade | category | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7 | fr | a | mango | 52 |
| 1 | 5 | fr | b | banana | 68 |
| 2 | 7 | fr | a | banana | 73 |
| 3 | 4 | it | c | mango | 70 |
| 4 | 5 | fr | b | banana | 99 |
| 5 | 9 | uk | a | apple | 29 |
| 6 | 3 | uk | a | mango | 83 |
| 7 | 0 | uk | b | banana | 59 |
| 8 | 2 | it | c | mango | 11 |
| 9 | 9 | uk | a | banana | 91 |
| 10 | 0 | uk | b | mango | 95 |
| 11 | 8 | uk | a | mango | 30 |
| 12 | 3 | uk | a | mango | 82 |
| 13 | 1 | it | b | banana | 78 |
| 14 | 3 | uk | a | apple | 76 |
| 15 | 6 | it | c | apple | 76 |
| 16 | 2 | it | c | mango | 10 |
| 17 | 1 | it | b | mango | 30 |
| 18 | 9 | uk | a | banana | 17 |
| 19 | 2 | it | c | mango | 58 |

Where each `id` belongs to a `grade` and lives in a `country`, and spends a certain `amount` on various fruits (`category`). Let's say the data covers a whole year. (Dataframe reproducible using the code below.)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id":[7,5,7,4,5,9,3,0,2,9,0,8,3,1,3,6,2,1,9,2],
    "country":["fr","fr","fr","it","fr","uk","uk","uk","it","uk","uk","uk","uk","it","uk","it","it","it","uk","it"],
    "grade":["a","b","a","c","b","a","a","b","c","a","b","a","a","b","a","c","c","b","a","c"],
    "category":["mango","banana","banana","mango","banana","apple","mango","banana","mango","banana","mango","mango","mango","banana","apple","apple","mango","mango","banana","mango"],
    "amount":[52,68,73,70,99,29,83,59,11,91,95,30,82,78,76,76,10,30,17,58]
})
```

I would like to add two columns to this DF.

First, I'd like a column giving the mean annual (ie total) spent on each `category` by each combination of `country` and `grade`. So, for example, the **Italy** **C**-grade people have spent the following on **mangos**:

`id: 4` total: 70

`id: 2` total: 11 + 10 + 58 = 79

So the mean annual **mango** spend for **Italy** **C**-grade people is 74.5. I'd like to find this value for all of the `country`/`grade`/`category` combinations.

The second column I want to add is the same but for the mean annual count for each combination.

**Desired output and the best I could come up with:**

I've managed to populate these two desired columns using the following code:

```
import math
combos = [[i,j,k] for i in set(df["country"]) for j in set(df["grade"]) for k in set(df["category"])]
for c in combos:
    x = df.loc[(df["country"]==c[0])&(df["grade"]==c[1])&(df["category"]==c[2])]
    m = x.groupby("id").sum()["amount"].mean()
    k = x.groupby("id").count()["amount"].mean()
    if math.isnan(m):
        m = 0
    if math.isnan(k):
        k = 0        
    c.append(m)
    c.append(k)
temp_grouping = pd.DataFrame(combos,columns=["country","grade","category","mean_totals","mean_counts"])

df = df.merge(temp_grouping,on=["country","grade","category"],how="left")
```

Which gives the desired output:

|  | id | country | grade | category | amount | mean_totals | mean_counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7 | fr | a | mango | 52 | 52 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | fr | b | banana | 68 | 167 | 2 |
| 2 | 7 | fr | a | banana | 73 | 73 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | it | c | mango | 70 | 74.5 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 | fr | b | banana | 99 | 167 | 2 |
| 5 | 9 | uk | a | apple | 29 | 52.5 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | uk | a | mango | 83 | 97.5 | 1.5 |
| 7 | 0 | uk | b | banana | 59 | 59 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | it | c | mango | 11 | 74.5 | 2 |
| 9 | 9 | uk | a | banana | 91 | 108 | 2 |
| 10 | 0 | uk | b | mango | 95 | 95 | 1 |
| 11 | 8 | uk | a | mango | 30 | 97.5 | 1.5 |
| 12 | 3 | uk | a | mango | 82 | 97.5 | 1.5 |
| 13 | 1 | it | b | banana | 78 | 78 | 1 |
| 14 | 3 | uk | a | apple | 76 | 52.5 | 1 |
| 15 | 6 | it | c | apple | 76 | 76 | 1 |
| 16 | 2 | it | c | mango | 10 | 74.5 | 2 |
| 17 | 1 | it | b | mango | 30 | 30 | 1 |
| 18 | 9 | uk | a | banana | 17 | 108 | 2 |
| 19 | 2 | it | c | mango | 58 | 74.5 | 2 |

The above code works, but it is not usable on my real data because it is pretty slow. I'm searching, therefore, for a faster/more efficient solution to my problem. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `mean_totals` column as follows:

```
mean_total_df = df.groupby(['country', 'category', 'grade']).apply(lambda x: x.amount.sum()/ x.id.nunique())
df['mean_totals'] = df.apply(lambda x: mean_total_df.loc[x.country, x.category, x.grade], axis=1)
```

which gives

```
0   7   fr  a   mango   52  52.0
1   5   fr  b   banana  68  167.0
2   7   fr  a   banana  73  73.0
3   4   it  c   mango   70  74.5
4   5   fr  b   banana  99  167.0
5   9   uk  a   apple   29  52.5
6   3   uk  a   mango   83  97.5
7   0   uk  b   banana  59  59.0
8   2   it  c   mango   11  74.5
9   9   uk  a   banana  91  108.0
10  0   uk  b   mango   95  95.0
11  8   uk  a   mango   30  97.5
12  3   uk  a   mango   82  97.5
13  1   it  b   banana  78  78.0
14  3   uk  a   apple   76  52.5
15  6   it  c   apple   76  76.0
16  2   it  c   mango   10  74.5
17  1   it  b   mango   30  30.0
18  9   uk  a   banana  17  108.0
19  2   it  c   mango   58  74.5
```

Comment: This works well and is about 20x faster than my best effort. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a double `groupby`. Once for the sum, once for the mean:

```
out = (df
 .groupby(['country', 'grade', 'category', 'id']).sum()
 .groupby(['country', 'grade', 'category']).mean()
)
```

output:

```
                        amount
country grade category        
fr      a     banana      73.0
              mango       52.0
        b     banana     167.0
it      b     banana      78.0
              mango       30.0
        c     apple       76.0
              mango       74.5
uk      a     apple       52.5
              banana     108.0
              mango       97.5
        b     banana      59.0
              mango       95.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work fast.. First group and compute the required details and merge with existing df.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
"id":[7,5,7,4,5,9,3,0,2,9,0,8,3,1,3,6,2,1,9,2],
"country":["fr","fr","fr","it","fr","uk","uk","uk","it","uk","uk","uk","uk","it","uk","it","it","it","uk","it"],
"grade":["a","b","a","c","b","a","a","b","c","a","b","a","a","b","a","c","c","b","a","c"],
"category":["mango","banana","banana","mango","banana","apple","mango","banana","mango","banana","mango","mango","mango","banana","apple","apple","mango","mango","banana","mango"],
"amount":[52,68,73,70,99,29,83,59,11,91,95,30,82,78,76,76,10,30,17,58]
})
intermediate_df = df.groupby(by=['country','grade','category','id'], as_index=False).agg(int_totals=pd.NamedAgg(column='amount',aggfunc='sum'),int_counts=pd.NamedAgg(column='id',aggfunc='count')).groupby(by=['country','grade','category'], as_index=False).agg(mean_totals=pd.NamedAgg(column='int_totals',aggfunc='mean'),mean_counts=pd.NamedAgg(column='int_counts',aggfunc='mean'))
output_df = pd.merge(df,intermediate_df, left_on = ['country','grade','category'],right_on = ['country','grade','category'], how='left')
print(output_df)
```

[Output_dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyxLU.png)

Comment: This is some of the most unmaintainable code I've seen in a while